# Oracle table Sequence generator is not working with JPA Composite primary key

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

My domain classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ZZ_USER_INFO", schema="PDS_OWNER")
public class User implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1317056412866001134L;  
    public User(){

    }   
    @EmbeddedId
    private UserPk userPk;  

    @Column(name="AGE", nullable=false)
    private int userAge;

    public UserPk getUserPk() {
        return userPk;
    }

    public void setUserPk(UserPk userPk) {
        this.userPk = userPk;
    }

    public int getUserAge() {
        return userAge;
    }

    public void setUserAge(int userAge) {
        this.userAge = userAge;
    }

}

public class UserPk implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 237150872186063319L;

        public UserPk(){

        }   

        @SequenceGenerator(name="ZZ_USER_INFO_SEQ", sequenceName="ZZ_USER_INFO_SEQ")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator="ZZ_USER_INFO_SEQ")
        @Column(name="USER_ID", nullable=false)
        private long userId;

        @Column(name="USER_NAME", nullable=false)
        private String userName;

        public long getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(long userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }   

    }
```

Here is my test method:

```
@Test
public void testCreatUser_success(){
    User user = new User();     

    UserPk userPk = new UserPk();
    userPk.setUserName("User2");

    user.setUserPk(userPk);     
    user.setUserAge(30);

    userRepository.save(user);      
}
```

When i use @SequenceGenerator with in an @EmbeddedId, it is not working in Oracle. In the table, i see the default value in USER_ID column which is Zero.

The same code works fine when I use @Id instead.

Can someone please help me on how to use Oracle sequecne generator with JPA @EmbeddedId ( Composite key)

Thanks for the assitance.

Comment: if you are auto-generating a PK value, why do you then need a composite?! The auto-generated value is UNIQUE. As for why it isn't working, that's why you have the JPA providers log which would show any usage of SEQUENCE

Comment: Can you add `@Embeddable` annotation to `User` class and try?

Comment: @harshavmb A class (`User`) cannot be both `@Entity` and `@Embeddable`; the `UserPk` class should be `@Embeddable` certainly, but then that is in all JPA docs so we have to assume it is a copy-paste error

Comment: Oops, my bad. Yes, `UserPk` should be `@Embeddable`. Thanks.. :)